# New years resolutions

Tags: technique, project

What kind of "New years resolutions" do you have as a photographer?

Comment: 21.2 megapixel :P Someone had to say it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Learn off-camera lighting techniques.

I bought a [speed light that's way more than what I need](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002EMY9Y) a few months ago, and recently bought a [cheapo radio trigger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002W3IXZW) for it. My goal is to learn as much as I can with one light before looking for an older manual flash for my second light.

Answer (score 9):

Look twice before pressing the shutter button in the hope that the results get that little bit better :) ... here's hoping!

Answer (score 7):

I'm Starting one of those 365 projects. And I plan on sharing on my blog how I use digiKam and Rawtherapee in my "workflow" (Not sure if I'm qualified to use that term :P ). There doesn't seem to be much on the inernet on the subject of photography on Linux... besides allot of people who seems satisfied with just using UFRaw + Gimp. :/

Comment: Raw Therapee is excellent, though when you want to do more forms of manipulation and some advanced techniques, GIMP is probably going to be useful to you.

Answer (score 5):

I think I'll start a 365 project again, I really need to start taking more pictures. And I really need to finish my A-Z project...

Comment: I just finished a Project 365. Fun, but it's going to be a while before I consider doing that again!

Answer (score 4):

Same as last year, increase the ratio of keepers without lowering my standards.

The year before I has a 1:10 ratio (I deleted 90% of images I took) and I finished with about a 1:8 ratio (deleting now 87%). I want to eventually stop shooting the bad pictures by better previsualization and finding more creative to make things look interesting.

I'm adding two this year:

- Learn panning (might seriously affect my previous goal though ;)
- Try out high-speed photography (water drops and splashes mostly)

Answer (score 3):

Get faster at post processing, I am currently about 2 months and 1000 pictures behind in processing, and I am currently on a Eurotrip racking up more, I need to get faster and picking keepers, and processing them for the web.

Answer (score 2):

Don't spend so much money on camera gear.

Comment: Noooooooooooo! :)

Comment: Mine is "Spend More on camera gear!" ;P

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing another project 365, just finished my first and it was really fun. And when doing it again, I'm planning to do more squares and other weird aspect ratios. Another goal is using my tripod more. And more portraits. That will do.

Answer (score 1):

Huuu ... nice one! :-)

Well here goes:

1. Learn how to use a flash properly - maybe even a ringflash.
2. Make my own webpage to sell my photos.
3. Organize my growing photo collection better.   (a new years resolution last year also)
4. Maybe get a fullframe camera! :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Take some walks to take some photos.

   - No, really, plan some more time to look for possibilites instead of taking pictures along on the walk to somewhere. Be it on bike or on foot, just go somewhere to explicitly concentrate on taking photos there.
2. Analyze my pictures from the last parties with [Exposureplot](http://www.cpr.demon.nl/prog_plotf.html) and decide on ~50mm or ~85mm prime.
3. Buy a flash. Maybe. :)

Answer (score 1):

For 2011 I've taken a step back from commercial work to focus on personal projects, but my main resolution is to print more black and white images, as most of my work has been colour the last few years.

Answer (score 0):

**Build my reputation** by sticking to my guns about charging for shoots requested of me and nailing the shoots in the process. I've only been doing this for six months so it's vital people don't get the "shoots for free" reputation going around.

**Master** some general off camera lighting for said shoots, thus building my reputation of being able to deliver.

**Check my framing** for tips of elbows, feet and even spacing.

Amongst other things.